# Getting "Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined ....""

Tags: protractor

I'm fairly new to Protractor and JS. I wrote a simple code to add few numbers using an online calculator. Add I am doing by calling a add() function where I am returning a Promise. This Promise I am handling in my it block where it is causing issue and giving above error.

Tried updating the versions but no help

```
describe("Using Protractor and working", function(){

    var resultsExpected = [];

    function add(a,b){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            element(by.model("first")).sendKeys(String(a));
            element(by.model("second")).sendKeys(String(b));
            element(by.id("gobutton")).click();     

            var len=0;
            len = resultsExpected.length;
            resultsExpected[len] = {value:String(a+b)};
             console.log("Length is: "+resultsExpected.length);
             console.log("Item inside: "+resultsExpected[len].value);
             resolve();
        });

    }

it("Addition from calc should give correct result", function(){
        browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');        

        add(2,4).then(function(ff){
            expect(element(by.css("h2.ng-binding")).getText()).toEqual("6");
            return add(5,3);
        }).then(function(ff){
            expect(element(by.css("h2.ng-binding")).getText()).toEqual("8");
            return add(5,8);
        }).then(function(ff){
            expect(element(by.css("h2.ng-binding")).getText()).toEqual("13");
        })

    })
})
```

```
Failures:
1) Using Protractor and working Addition from calc should give correct result
  Message:
[31m    Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"[0m
  Stack:
    Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
        at runWaitForAngularScript.then (D:\JavaScriptWorkSpace\FirstProtractor\protractor\built\browser.js:463:23)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (D:\JavaScriptWorkSpace\FirstProtractor\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (D:\JavaScriptWorkSpace\FirstProtractor\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (D:\JavaScriptWorkSpace\FirstProtractor\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (D:\JavaScriptWorkSpace\FirstProtractor\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
        at D:\JavaScriptWorkSpace\FirstProtractor\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)Error
        at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (D:\JavaScriptWorkSpace\FirstProtractor\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
        at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as getText] (D:\JavaScriptWorkSpace\FirstProtractor\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
        at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as getText] (D:\JavaScriptWorkSpace\FirstProtractor\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
        at D:\JavaScriptWorkSpace\FirstProtractor\WorkinWithDropDown.js:55:45
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: More details discussed here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2643

Comment: browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); none of them helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
it("Addition from calc should give correct result", async() =>{
       await brwoser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
       await browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');        
    })
});
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

This may not help, because I don't see `browser.wait()` in your code, but FWIW we spent days debugging this exact error message, and eventually fixed it by updating all `browser.wait()` calls with an explicit timeouts.  E.g.

```
browser.wait(condition, 5000);
```

Instead of

```
browser.wait(condition);
```

We started by verifying that `browser.waitForAngularEnabled()` was set to true, which it was (we're testing a pure Angular app with Cucumber/Protrator/Selenium/Chai, no non-angular pages, so no reason to turn off `waitForAngular`).  So no luck there.

Then, after much experimentation, we concluded that `browser.wait()` *doesn't always throw an exception and fail the test when the expected condition never becomes true*, UNLESS you provide the timeout argument.  Without the timeout, the best case scenario was that the test would hit the global cucumber timeout and we would get an unhelpful generic failure message.  The worst case scenario was that execution would occasionally continue to the next feature, while the first feature was timing out in the background.  When the first feature finally timed out, it caused the second feature to fail with the cryptic message `both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined`.  There's no mention of this behavior in [the documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) for `wait()`.

We tried increasing the global cucumber timeout and setting a global protractor timeout, but it had no effect.  So we did a blanket update to always provide the timeout parameter, and haven't seen the error since.

I suspect that the whole misadventure might be related to our use of Chai instead of Jasmine, since the documentation mentions `jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval`, so maybe there's some assumption in the code that we're breaking.